# How to detect if EditBox is empty

Tags: android, csv, android-edittext

Iam new to programming... still a beginner in Android...

I have a Login Activity, when I clikc submit it goes to another Activity.
I have an EditBox which it enters.
I want to detect if the EditBox is empty

If it is empty I want to avoid clicking a button which I am clicking using the
etNumber.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener()

This will save the data to a csv file...

The idea is that any empty editText will not be saved... and thus have empty lines in the csv...

Comment: what is EditBox? it is EditTextView ?

Comment: you can retrieve EditText text length in your activity onCreate or onResume if it's length is zero then you can disable your button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. But for the above problem statement the below code should work.

```
<Your EditText>.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(!editText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
         //Your code
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you this seemed to work.... Thank you very much.,..  I used .isEmpty, but I din't use .trim  I guess I should have tried it..

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText editText  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText().toString())) {
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "EditText is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
 else {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "EditText is Not Empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kotlin (which you should) then below 1 line statement uses the kotlin inline extension to check for the emptiness,

```
editText.text.isNotEmpty().apply { 
    //do something
 }
```

here `editText` is id of your edit text , which you can get with below code,

```
val editText= findViewById(R.id.et_message) as EditText
```